# Triple Integral $\iiint x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n}dV$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate:
$$\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 1} x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n} dV $$

I have tried to convert to spherical polars and then compute the integral, but it gets really messy because of the 2n power. Any tips?

Comment: Spherical coordinates definitely seems like the way to go. Your integration occurs within a sphere of radius $1$, which simply integrating $r$ from $0$ to $1$ and letting your angles map out the whole of a sphere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First observation: it is symmetric in $x,y,z$, so by linearity we have
$$\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 1} x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n} dV =3\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 1} z^{2n} dV.$$

Choosing [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates) it becomes
$$3\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 1} (r\cos \theta)^{2n} dV$$
where $dV= r^2 \sin \theta \ \text{d}r \ \text{d}\theta \ \text{d}\phi$.
Thus the integral simplifies to
$$3 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^1 r^{2(n+1)} (\cos \theta)^{2n} \sin \theta \ \text{d}r \ \text{d}\theta \ \text{d}\phi = \frac{3}{2n+3}2 \pi  \int_0^{\pi}(\cos \theta)^{2n} \sin \theta \ \text{d}\theta. $$
Using that 
$$\int_0^{\pi}(\cos \theta)^{2n} \sin \theta \ \text{d}\theta = \frac{2}{2n+1} $$
we have
$$\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2 \leqslant 1} x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n} dV= \frac{3}{2n+3}2 \pi  \frac{2}{2n+1}.$$

Comment: The trigonometric integral simplifies to $$2\int_0^1 x^{2n} \text{d}x $$ by using the axis symmetry at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and substitution by $\cos \theta = x$.

Comment: My tips are: first use symmetry, then spherical coordinates, then with some Fubini and elementary integrals you can solve it.

Comment: beat me to it (+1)